# Как получить число π в Perl?

Tags: математика, perl

Существует ли способ получения числа π в Perl с помощью одной строки?

1. Как получить число π с помощью однострочного математического ряда?
2. Как получить число π с помощью встроенных модулей Perl?

Результат должен быть примерно такой:

```
$pi = ... # Вместо ... однострочное выражение, возвращающее π
```

Comment: какая точность вам требуется? не потеряется ли точность в дальнейших ваших вычислениях? вы это оценивали? или у вас задание - лишь получение данного числа?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667543/code-in-perl-for-pi-calculation

Comment: @nexoma, нужна точность около 10 знаков.

Comment: @nexoma, эту ссылку я видел, но там код в двух строчках, а мне нужно одну.

Comment: `$pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;` - одна строка с достаточной точностью :)

Comment: по вопросу 2
perl
use Math::Trig;

print "Pi = ", pi, "\n";
Pi = 3.14159265358979

Comment: @АлексейР, это хорошо, конечно, но трудно запомнить. Не зря же, например, в питоне, есть `math.pi`. Хотелось бы что-то, что проще запомнить.

Comment: ;) а как вы ряд лейбница запомните?  странноватое утверждение. вот с рядами, коде-гольф https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=159377

Comment: "Запоминанию может помогать соблюдение стихотворного размера:
Три, четырнадцать, пятнадцать, девять два, шесть пять, три пять
Восемь девять, семь и девять, три два, три восемь, сорок шесть
Два шесть четыре, три три восемь, три два семь девять, пять ноль два
Восемь восемь и четыре, девятнадцать, семь, один" (Википедия)

Comment: @nexoma, если этот ряд лейбница понять, то запомнить его будет гораздо проще чем набор цифр. А вообще, конечно, проще использовать модуль Math.

Comment: не смейтеь над собой. pi - константа, в одном месте вставили и используется на всём проекте. на физических симуляциях таких констант десятки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое устроит?

```
use Math::Trig ':pi';
```